# bash - How to use grep on a variable

Tags: bash

Alright so I have a server listening on a specific port which accepts a PIN code and replies with a "correct" or "wrong" message.

I created the following script to try all possible 3 digit pins:

```
i=0
While [ $i -le 999]
 do 
      echo $i |nc localhost port
      ((i++)) 
done
```

When I execute this I get the following output:

```
Wrong

Wrong

Wrong

Wrong

Correct

Wrong

Wrong

...
```

My question is, how can I modify this script so that it uses grep to show only the "correct" messages?

I tried the following:

```
i=0

While [ $i -le 999]
 do 
      output=$(echo $i |nc localhost port)

      if [ grep -q "Correct" $output -eq 0]
      then
             echo "the right pin is $i"
     ((i++)) 
done
```

But for some reason it didnt work either

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Why use `grep` when you can test for equality? `if [[ "$output" == Correct ]] then ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often the immediate answer would be "use `$(...)`". But going by your example, that would be the wrong answer, because it'd be confusing *output* with the *exit status* – you're comparing something to 0, so that 'something' has to be the exit status.

Side note: You're also confusing *input* with *command arguments*. When grep is given additional arguments, it expects them to be files, not direct strings. You need `echo "$output" | grep -q "Correct"` if all you have is a string variable without a corresponding file.

Back to the exit status. The status is stored in the `$?` variable (until the next command overwrites it):

```
echo $output | grep -q "Correct"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "OK!"
fi
```

Or using bash's syntax:

```
echo $output | grep -q "Correct"
if (( $? == 0 )); then
    echo "OK!"
fi
```

But, that's a bit redundant, because comparing exit status to 0 is what `if` *already does all the time*. That `[` isn't a special syntax element – it's just a command by itself, which exits with 0 if the comparison succeeded. You can just as well use any other command in its place:

```
if echo $output | grep -q "Correct"; then
    echo "OK!"
fi
```

Finally, you don't really need *grep* at all here – you can check the variable's contents directly. What you're currently checking is whether the word "Correct" occurs anywhere in the string – that could be reimplemented using bash's `[[` wildcard matching:

```
if [[ $output == *Correct* ]]; then
```

(The same can be done in pure sh using `case $output in ...`.)

And if the string is always *exactly* the word "Correct" or not, that's even simpler:

```
if [[ $output == Correct ]]; then

if [ "$output" = Correct ]; then
```

Comment: Wildcard matching in plain sh, if you _really_ want to use `if...fi` for some reason: `if ! case $output in *Correct*) false; esac; then ...`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an AND list to quickly check exit status:

> AND and OR lists are sequences of one or more pipelines separated by the && and  ||  control operators, respectively.  AND and OR lists are executed with left associativity.  An
> AND list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 && command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.
>
> <sub>(from `man bash`)</sub>

So in this case, you probably want this in your while loop:

```
echo $i |nc localhost port | grep -q "Correct" && echo "OK!"
```

Or maybe something like

```
for i in {1..999}
do
    echo $i |nc localhost port | grep -q "Correct" && echo "OK!"
done
```

optionally with a `break` to exit the loop if there's only one "Correct" number. Or maybe a while or until loop that tests for correctness... lots of options